# How do I recalculate the gradient after changing the input? Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, gradient

I am trying to do something like this without redefining a = f(x,y):

```
a = f(x,y)
find gradient of a with respect to x
change x
find gradient of a with respect to x
find gradient of a with respect to y
```

I tried a partial example below but it just gives me an error. Does anyone know how I can do this without redefining the original function everytime?

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([2.], requires_grad=True)
>>> y = 10*x**2
>>> torch.autograd.grad(y,x, retain_graph=True)
(tensor([40.]),)
>>> x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
>>> torch.autograd.grad(y,x, retain_graph=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/Philip/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 157, in grad
    inputs, allow_unused)
RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I recalculate the gradient after changing the input?

In general you need to recompute the output with the new input.

Consider the way that the backpropagation algorithm works. Depending on the form of `f`, different intermediate results will need to be saved for later use by the backpropagation algorithm. These intermediate results may or may not depend on the original value of `x`, even when computing the gradient w.r.t. `y`.

For example, if `f(x,y) = g(h(x,y))` then by the chain rule `df/dy = dg/dh * dh/dy`. To make this a little more concrete lets consider the case where `g` is some non-linear function and `h(x,y) = x*y`. Then we have that `df/dy = g'(h(x,y))*x`. The reason backpropagation works efficiently here is that it caches the intermediate value of `h(x,y)` during forward pass, so all it needs to do is plug that value into `g'` during the backward pass. If you change the value of `x`, then the cached value of `h(x,y)` will no longer be the correct value needed to compute the gradient you are interested in (which should be using the value of `h` computed using the new value of `x`). Therefore you must recompute the forward pass again to store the correct cached values.